# Search and casing issue with nuget packages from nuget.pkg.github.com

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget

We are using `nuget.pkg.github.com` to host nuget packages from our private repositories. In general, this is working fine.

However, using the Visual Studio package manager, there are two minor issues that are kind of annoying.

1. The search function is not working properly

For packages hosted on nuget, it used a wildcard search. So I would find the package `MyCompany.Data.Something` by just typing `Something` or `omet`.
However for the packages hosted at github, its only working if the prefix matches exactly. `MyComp` would show results, but not `Company` or `Something`.

2. The Install/Update tabs show package names from github all in lower-case. Its using the correct casing in the "Browse" tab and in the list view.

Is this due to API limitations of the github nuget host or anything I can do about it?